# Pandas dataframe randomly shuffle some column values in groups

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby, permutation, shuffle

I would like to shuffle some column values but only within a certain group and only a certain percentage of rows within the group. For example, per group, I want to shuffle n% of values in column b with each other.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'grouper_col':[1,1,2,3,3,3,3,4,4], 'b':[12, 13, 16, 21, 14, 11, 12, 13, 15]})

   grouper_col   b
0            1  12
1            1  13
2            2  16
3            3  21
4            3  14
5            3  11
6            3  12
7            4  13
8            4  15
```

Example output:

```
   grouper_col   b
0            1  13
1            1  12
2            2  16
3            3  21
4            3  11
5            3  14
6            3  12
7            4  15
8            4  13
```

I found

```
df.groupby("grouper_col")["b"].transform(np.random.permutation)
```

but then I have no control over the percentage of shuffled values.

Thank you for any hints!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `numpy` to create a function like this (it takes a numpy array for input)

```
import numpy as np

def shuffle_portion(arr, percentage): 
    shuf = np.random.choice(np.arange(arr.shape[0]),  
                            round(arr.shape[0]*percentage/100), 
                            replace=False) 
    arr[np.sort(shuf)] = arr[shuf] 
    return arr
```

`np.random.choice` will choose a set of indexes with the size you need. Then the corresponding values in the given array can be rearranged in the shuffled order. Now this should shuffle 3 values out of the 9 in cloumn `'b'`

```
df['b'] = shuffle_portion(df['b'].values, 33)
```

---

**EDIT**:
To use with `apply`, you need to convert the passed dataframe to an array inside the function (explained in the comments) and create the return dataframe as well

```
def shuffle_portion(_df, percentage=50): 
    arr = _df['b'].values
    shuf = np.random.choice(np.arange(arr.shape[0]),  
                            round(arr.shape[0]*percentage/100), 
                            replace=False) 
    arr[np.sort(shuf)] = arr[shuf] 
    _df['b'] = arr
    return _df
```

Now you can just do

```
df.groupby("grouper_col", as_index=False).apply(shuffle_portion)
```

It would be better practice if you pass the name of the column which you need to shuffle, to the function (`def shuffle_portion(_df, col='b', percentage=50): arr = _df[col].values ...`)

Comment: Thank you. That works. However, when using that in a groupby statement, I have to set a non-integer index somehow, otherwise I get an index error. After setting another index, I can use: `df.groupby("grouper_col", as_index=False)["b"].apply(shuffle_portion, percentage=50) `and this is exactly what I needed. Do you know why I get this index error? (KeyError: "None of [Int64Index([0, 2], dtype='int64')] are in the [index]")

Comment: You are trying to apply the function into a groupby object instead of the df. [Refer to the docs first.](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply.html) It says that your function should take a dataframe as input and return a dataframe. I did not know this was the usage when I answered and it's not clear what you are trying to do

Comment: How would you rephrase "For example, per group, I want to shuffle n% of values in column b with each other" so that it is clearer? I though "per group" would show that I need to use groupby of some sort

Comment: Sorry I missed that and sorry about the delayed response. The error occurs since `apply` takes grouped dataframe as its input argument. To deal with that, you have to convert `'b'`'s values to an array inside the function. I will update the answer